# How can I be sure that I am accessing the correct value to use in Swift

Tags: swift

This is a basic question for me, I want to know, can I be 100% sure that after updating a variable to new value is 100% safe to access and read it in next line of code? or maybe it would take some internal delay of processing and it is not safe to use in this way.

*The use case would be updating and reading values that they are happing in very very short time almost zero nano sec delay like gestures.*

for example I want update `value2` with exact same value of `value1`, but I do not know it is a safe way, therefore I am using second function that I am declaring a constant for updating `value1` and `value2`. The downside of second function as you know is using an extra constant.

```
var value1: Int = 0
var value2: Int = 0

func valueFunction1() {
    
    value1 = 50
    value2 = value1
 
}

func valueFunction2() {
    
    let value: Int = 50
    
    value1 = value
    value2 = value
 
}
```

Comment: Assuming that there's nothing mutating the values from a different thread, it'll always be safe to access and read.

Comment: there's nothing mutating the values, all the codes are as I showed in up.

Comment: Then you're safe to use the values on the next line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These questions come up when you are writing concurrent code (code that runs on multiple threads at the same time.) In that case you have to take special precautions to make sure another thread doesn't change values out from under your running code.

Assuming you are not writing multi-threaded code (And based on the very basic nature of your questions, you should avoid that for now) you can be absolutely certain that variables take on their new values as soon as your change them. Any given function runs "synchronously" (top to bottom) and finishes each line before moving on to the next. (Compilers and CPUs can play some games with your code that stretch those rules a little, but the burden is on the compiler to make sure that variables have the correct values by the time the next line is executed.)